# Unable to launch the Chrome headless browser in Windows 7 using Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

```
 **Sinppet**  

 if (os.contains("win")) {
                    System.out.println("OS: WINDOWS");  
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", localPath+"chromedriver.exe");
                    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
                    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                } else if (os.contains("mac")) {
                    System.out.println("OS: MAC");              
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", localPath+"chromedriver_mac64");
                    return new ChromeDriver();
                }
```

**Error I am facing**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@id='user_id'] (tried for 180 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at com.adp.marketplace.frwk.selenium.SeleniumFunctions.waitForVisibilityByXpath(SeleniumFunctions.java:510)
    at com.adp.marketplace.prm.SSOTestInPRMSteps.The_user_logged_into_PRM_with_valid_cred(SSOTestInPRMSteps.java:28)
    at ?.Given the user logged into PRM with valid creds(com/adp/marketplace/prm/SSOTestsInPRM.feature:7)
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument for headless is wrong, should be :

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

With -- before headless , just like you are adding arguments from shortcut : 
[image]